# What is the difference between TeamsActivityHandler and ActivityHandler?

Tags: python-3.x, botframework, microsoft-teams

In most documentation you'll see:

```py
class BotHandler(ActivityHandler):
    async def on_message_activity(self, turn_context: TurnContext):
        await turn_context.send_activity("Hello!")
```

However, [some Python examples](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-python/blob/96299630faaf05b807fae2106f484c7371362e1a/tests/teams/scenarios/create-thread-in-channel/bots/create_thread_in_teams_bot.py#L12) will use `TeamsActivityHandler` instead:

```py
class BotHandler(TeamsActivityHandler):
    async def on_message_activity(self, turn_context: TurnContext):
        message = MessageFactory.text("first message")
        channel_id = teams_get_channel_id(turn_context.activity)
```

I've noticed that

1. When inheriting from `TeamsActivityHandler`, I can overload `on_teams_channel_created()` that gets called when a new channel is created.
2. When inheriting from `ActivityHandler`, I can overload `on_members_added_activity()` to greet new users (welcome message).

How can I use both at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. If you inherit from `TeamsActivityHandler` you may override `on_teams_members_added()` instead.

This is rather counter intuitive because when you inherit from `TeamsActivityHandler` (which in turn inherits from `TeamsActivity`) you assume get the same functionality (i.e: be able to override the same function(s)). This does not seem to be the case due to the [super() used here](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-python/blob/63fd1735452501636af4680e210e2f398a79368d/libraries/botbuilder-core/botbuilder/core/teams/teams_activity_handler.py#L736).

If you inherit from `TeamsActivity` you may override `on_members_added_activity()` as per usual.

Not sure if this is a bug or just weird design.

Answer (score 1):

Bots created using the Microsoft Bot Framework can be used for multiple purposes (it's a general-purpose bot framework), e.g. for web chat, slack, etc. - Teams is just one of those possible "Channels", as they're called. As a result, the 'main' class at play is `ActivityHandler`, but for Teams development there's a derived class (`TeamsActivityHandler`) which has some additional Teams-specific wrappers.

Comment: Is it possible to use functionality from both classes? For example, my bot may want to greet new users with a welcome message when the app is installed (via a private message) - you can do this by inheriting from `ActivityHandler` and overriding `on_members_added_activity`, however, my bot is also active in a Teams channel, and as such I'd like to overload `on_members_added_activity()` - but it's not a present on the `ActivityHandler`, only on `TeamsActivityHandler`. I'm a bit lost to how to support both events/activities within one handler.

Comment: I don't know anything about python, so I can't help too much in terms of language, but in .Net I know that, for instance, when I use `TeamsActivityHandler` I can access both it's _own_ functionality and everything it inherits from `ActivityHandler` - I can't see why python would be any different.